# Offset Overlapping Routes w/out Schematics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, route, transit

I'm currently working on showing route frequency and productivity for a transit system. The data is by route and I'd like to have the routes offset to better visualize the data.

I've researched this and have found that I can use a combinations of geometric networks and the ArcGIS Schematic extension. Is is possible to do this without the Schematic extension?

I know I could simply change the symbology of every route line, but with them routes and going in multiple directions, simply changing the offset in the line's symbology really wouldn't work.

In the past I've manually offset each route and I'd really like to not have to do that again.

Comment: Be aware that a network dataset and a geometric network are not the same thing. If your transit system is in a network dataset you won't be able to make a geometric network

Comment: @Midavalo Thankfully the transit routes aren't in a network dataset! I think  creating the geometric network then using ArcGIS schematics is my best option.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into [Representations](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/what-are-representations-.htm) if you have the appropriate ArcGIS license level.

> Representations allow you to customize the appearance of features by
>   storing symbol information with the feature geometry

This would allow you to leave the feature's geometry in its actual location, and offset its symbology for better display.

(For your purposes though, ArcGIS Schematics sounds ideal. You could request a trial license, and potentially justify its value.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Stephen. I really appreciate any and all guidance. I'll look into Representations, but I think you're right, using ArcGIS Schematics is probably my best option.